# Is it possible to change the location for the attached local storages in Azure Cloud Service Roles?

Tags: azure

Per default setup, a attached local storage will end up in the directory at:
C:\Resources\Directory\..

an example C:\Resources\Directory\002823b0b8854e3ca2768025d08464e9.Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.Boot.c1

Are there any options to shorten this other then changing the RoleName (The project Name in Visual studio) and the Storage Folder Name (Setting in .csdef).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to change the location of Local resources.

However (undocumented) you can (almost) freely write to `C:` drive. All you need to do is run an elevated [start-up task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) to create a new folder under `C:\` (say `C:\my_funky_folder`) and set ACL to `full control` for `Everyone`.

The latter is required if you do not run your role code elevated, which is suggested security best practice. By default your code will run under low privileged account, which has no permissions on `C:` drive, other than the defined Local Resource folders.

Comment: okay. Not a big fan of this for production, never know if it could change in the future.

Comment: Looking for alternative solution, trying to figure out if rolename can be set/changed independent of the visual studio project name.

Comment: well, it survives for 4 years now and at least 5 Major releases of the SDK (1.3 ... 2.0). There are also hundreds of **production** systems running [Azure RunMe](https://github.com/RobBlackwell/AzureRunMe) which heavily relies on the fact that `C:` is there and free. And anyway the structure is locked down to SDK version used.